# Installation and shared folders in different disk

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition.

If the instance root directory is `D:\Instance\Folder1`, do I need to change the shared feature directory from `C:\ProgramFiles\Blah\Blah` to `D:\ProgramFiles\Blah\Blah`, and do I need to do the same to the shared features directory `(x86)`?

I changed the instance root directory, will that make the default change to the other two and bring it to `D:\`?

Comment: You can always try it and back out if that is what you do not like.  Read this for some good info.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/is-it-useful-to-have-the-sql-server-instance-root-directory-on-a-separate-drive

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server seems to require some files on the C: drive, regardless of what you select.

During installation, you've got the option of where certain things should be stored. If you specified that each location you could specify was on your D: drive, then anything that was placed on your C: drive probably has to be there.

Moving these directories manually is not a good idea; you would need to update the paths the SQL Server engine uses to access those files

Note that shared files are shared amongst different instances on the same machine (at a minimum). If you already have an instance installed, I do not believe that changing to a new directory for shared files when installing an additional instance will update your existing instance(s). Best case scenario, you'll wind up with "shared" files in two different places, *not* being shared by your instances. Worst case scenario (unlikely, but not necessarily impossible), your existing instance(s) could become non-functional, if they're looking for files in the old location, and the installer has moved them to a new one.